# git keeps asking for password via putty

Tags: git, ssh, putty

I have created an online repo, then I have also generated and configured keys on my computer at work. Everything works fine.

But when I connect to the same computer from home via VPN and putty, I cannot push anymore, git always asks for password.

I can push on my computer at work, but when I work remotely with putty, the push command stops working. git shows me a prompt and asks for password.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be you can try this

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

and have you configured your git password in .git config file?

Comment: Probably remote repository doesn't even accept password login

Comment: No, I haven't. It's not my own git server, it's repo created on a website like Github, I don't think I have the privilege to configure the git password. And I've already generated the keys, as I said, I can push when I'm on the computer at work. But when I connect to the same computer via Putty, I always get a password prompt.